# How to Update the Following Table with MERGE in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update, oracle12c

I have the following data set (Oracle 12):

```
Table X
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
| COLN    | COLM   | COLK          | COLP   |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
| 1       | 500    | K1            | 777    |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+

Table A
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
| COL1    | COL2   | COL3          | COL4   |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
| 1       | K1     | 500           | B      |
| 1       | K2     | 500           | NULL   |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+

Table B
+---------+--------+---------+
| COLZ    | COLX   | COLW    |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 1       | K1     | 777     |
| 1       | K2     | 678     |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

The three tables have the following commonality:

`X.COLN` = `A.COL1` = `B.COLZ`
`X.COLk` = `A.COL2` = `B.COLX`
`X.COLM` = `A.COL3`

I need to write a query which retrieves values for the following columns in one query:

`X.COLK`, `X.COLP`, `B.COLX`, `B.COLW`

The ultimate goal is, if the following conditions are met:

- If there more than one record in Table A where `A.COL1`'s and `A.COL3`'s are matching (and there is a corresponding record in Table X)
- And one of the rows is not null, e.g. `A.COL4 = B`, and another one is NULL

I update Table X to replace `X.COLK`, `X.COLP` (K1 and 777) in my `MERGE` statement with values in Table B (`B.COLX`, `B.COLW` -- K2 and 678).

Is this possible?

```
MERGE INTO X FX
USING (
    SELECT COLX ONGOING_X, COLW ONGOING_W 
    FROM B 
    WHERE (COLZ, COLX) IN 
        (SELECT COL1, COL2 
         FROM A 
         WHERE COL3 = ? 
            AND COL1 = ? 
            AND COL4 IS NULL)
) NEW_B
    ON (FX.COLk = ?
        AND FX.COLP = ?)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        FX.COLk = NEW_B.ONGOING_X,
        FX.FOLP = NEW_B.ONGOING_W;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Something in light of what I updated in the original post. But I need Values of `COLK` and `COLP` in `NEW_B` in order to make the matched on `ON` clause, but how?

Comment: So, does it mean you want to update only those rows in X which have 2 matching rows (one with col4 null and another with col4 not null) and nothing else. what if they have 3 rows one with null and 2 with not null?

Comment: @KaushikNayak That's a possibility to have 3 rows, 1 with NULL and 2 with not NULL `A.COL4`. However, the 3rd row would not be having a matching condition of `X.COLK = A.COL2`. We're matching that one specific row from X with A (using COL1/COL2/COL3 = COLN/M/K). Then using COL1 and COL3, I'll look for a row which its `COL4` is NULL (there is only one such record is going to be available). However, for my `MERGE`, not only I need to identify such row,`COL4 = NULL`,in order to find the corresponding row in Table B, but if I want to use `MERGE`, I need to have access to the original Table X row.

Comment: Ok. It's hard for me to recall. Could you check and understand my solution( and may be modify it slightly to handle that condition as well) ? The general structure of the statement needn't be changed, only some conditions might

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do a  `MERGE` using `ROWID`.

```
MERGE INTO x tgt USING (
     WITH c AS (
          SELECT col1,
                 col3,
                 MAX(
                      CASE
                           WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN col2
                      END
                 ) AS col2 --Ongoing col2 as indicated from col4
          FROM a
          GROUP BY col1,
                   col3
          HAVING COUNT(
               CASE
                    WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN 1
               END
          ) = 1 AND COUNT(col4) = 1 --Contains one and exactly one NULL and one NON NULL
     ) SELECT x.rowid AS rid,
              b.*
       FROM x
       JOIN c ON c.col1 = x.coln AND c.col3 = x.colm 
       JOIN b ON b.colz = c.col1 AND b.colx = c.col2 --Join with ongoing value from c( a.k.a table A )
)
src ON ( tgt.rowid = src.rid ) --ROWID match
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tgt.colk = src.colx,
tgt.colp = src.colw;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b9ec9f2c6ab04205b90f30bbad4923c9)